# Требуется помошь Ошибка в JS

Tags: jquery

Помогите разобраться, в консоли выдается ошибка в function($) {
Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name

```js
    function($) {
 var Utility = function() {
 /**
  * Local reference to network status
  * 
  * @access private
  * @var Boolean
  */
 var networkStatus;
 
 /**
  * Check network status and manage application cache forced refresh
  * 
  * @access public
  * @return Boolean
  */
 this.checkNetworkStatus = function() {
  // Only check status and optional refresh if application cache and local storage are supported
  if(!Modernizr.applicationcache || !Modernizr.localstorage || !rvzrOfflineCache) {
   return false;
  }
  
  // Try to detect if are online/offline through a more reliable async request
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: rvzrBaseURI + "index.php?option=com_responsivizer&task=dummycontroller.dummytask",
   async: true,
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // Store existing status
    var previousStatus = localStorage.getItem('networkStatus');
    networkStatus = true;
    localStorage.setItem('networkStatus', networkStatus);
    // If we was offline it's the moment to force a refresh to get now fresh cache resources
    if(previousStatus === 'false') {
     // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
     window.location.reload();
    }
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
    networkStatus = false;
    localStorage.setItem('networkStatus', networkStatus);
   }
  }); 
 };
```

Comment: Ну русским же языком написано — должно быть имя функции

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/closure#bloki-koda-i-tsikly-iife впрочем очевидно вас надо IIFE

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function($) {
 var Utility = function() {
 /**
  * Local reference to network status
  * 
  * @access private
  * @var Boolean
  */
 var networkStatus;
 
 /**
  * Check network status and manage application cache forced refresh
  * 
  * @access public
  * @return Boolean
  */
 this.checkNetworkStatus = function() {
  // Only check status and optional refresh if application cache and local storage are supported
  if(!Modernizr.applicationcache || !Modernizr.localstorage || !rvzrOfflineCache) {
   return false;
  }
  
  // Try to detect if are online/offline through a more reliable async request
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: rvzrBaseURI + "index.php?option=com_responsivizer&task=dummycontroller.dummytask",
   async: true,
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    // Store existing status
    var previousStatus = localStorage.getItem('networkStatus');
    networkStatus = true;
    localStorage.setItem('networkStatus', networkStatus);
    // If we was offline it's the moment to force a refresh to get now fresh cache resources
    if(previousStatus === 'false') {
     // Browser downloaded a new app cache.
     window.location.reload();
    }
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
    networkStatus = false;
    localStorage.setItem('networkStatus', networkStatus);
   }
  }); 
 }}})(jQuery); // мало скобок и дописать чутка
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```